# ScheduledExecutorService.awaitTermination() returns false even though no tasks are running

Tags: scheduledexecutorservice

My application is invoking:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
// schedule some tasks
scheduler.shutdown();
if (!scheduler.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
  System.out.println("Boom!");
```

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get `awaitTermination()` to return `true`. This is especially confusing because I can see (using a debugger) that the scheduler thread is completely idle.

Using `scheduler.getQueue()` I noticed that exactly one task remains on the queue after `scheduler.shutdown()` is invoked. The task status is "Not completed" meaning that it is pending for execution and not cancelled.

- Why isn't `shutdown()` canceling this task?
- Is the task remaining on the queue preventing `awaitTermination()` from returning `true`?

I know about `shutdownNow()` but I don't want to interrupt running tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

Per https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7069418 any tasks on the queue will prevent `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` from shutting down. In some cases it goes on to say that even cancelled tasks can prevent shutdown but this wasn't the case for me.

I incorrectly assumed that `shutdown()` would cancel pending tasks that were not actively running. This is not the case.

`shutdownNow()` cancels pending tasks, but it also interrupts running tasks (which I don't want to do). So, if your goal is to cancel all pending tasks and wait for running tasks to complete (without interruption) you need only invoke `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false)` before `shutdown()`.